# What kind of methods are most commonly used to interpolate a relief?

Tags: qgis, raster, visualisation, terrain

I have got a topographic plan with height measurements which I converted to point shape file with height value in attributes. I was wondering, what kind of methods are most commonly used to interpolate a relief? My guess is that for volume measurements it would be TIN interpolation (for example, QGIS plugin Interpolation), but for pretty visualizations, one of the spline interpolators (SAGA from Processing toolbar) might be more appropriate.

Comment: Mairis, This is going to be a hard question to get good answers for because 1) there are hundreds of different interpolation methods for elevation data, and 2) there is no best, or even most appropriate, method. The choice of an interpolator very much depends on your application, the source data characteristics (e.g. amount of error, source), and algorithm availability (software consideration). That's a lot to take into account. Can you tell us more? What's your point density? Where did they come from? What's your application?

Comment: I have approximately 4 hectars with 145 height points. They are from tpopgraphic plan with accuracy X,Y,Z~5 cm. The measurements were placed evenly.

Comment: That's fairly low point density for an elevation dataset. You may want to explore something like kriging, which performs better than many interpolators when point density is low.